# Outputting Batch Command to Variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I do not have a strong background in batch scripts, so apologies if there is an obvious answer.

I am trying to direct the output of a command prompt to a variable. I can output it to a file like this

```
go test -race > output.txt
```

In this case, output.txt gets populated with the output of go test -race. What I am trying to do is output it to a variable, something along the lines of

```
set iamavariable=nothotdog
go test -race > %iamavariable%
echo %location%
```

This creates a file called nothotdog that has the output of go test -race, and echoes nothotdog, instead of echoing the output of go test -race

Comment: Why did you `echo %location%`? That looks nonsense to me.

Comment: Sorry, it was a copy and paste error

Answer (score 1):

To correctly get the result of a command, you need a `for` loop.

```
for /f %%p in ('your command') do set result=%%p
echo %result%
```

---

If the command was outputting more than a single word/number/character/digit then perhaps this would be better:

```
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('go test -race') Do Set "result=%%A"
Echo %result%
```

Comment: If the command was outputting more than a single word/number/character/digit then perhaps this would be better: `For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('go test -race') Do Set "location=%%A"`